# How to pull Javascript from a specific element on a page from the front end

Tags: javascript, html

So I found a really cool web structure I'd like to implement into one of my sites on http://www.nextendweb.com/demo/smartslider2/. There are **settings gearboxes** that rotate as the user scrolls down the page.

It's being done using the Transform: Matrix function. I would post a code-block of the element but I can't seem to locate the JS behind it. This is not my site, so I obviously only have access to the front-end.

HTML

```
<div class="cog cog2" style="transform: matrix(-0.68823, 0.72548, -0.72548, -0.68823, 0, 0);"></div>
```

CSS

```
#technicaldetails .cog {
background: url(images/bigcog.png) no-repeat 0 0;
width: 502px;
height: 476px;
position: absolute;
```

}

the element in question is located in a div with Id's cog1 & cog2 if you're having trouble locating it on the web page.

could anyone guide me in finding the JS behind this element from the front-end? I tried inspecting and looking through the sources...

Comment: The `transform` property doesn't need script to make it work. It will be handled by the browser based on the parameters you provide to it.

Comment: Can one add these parameters in respect to pixels scrolled without JS? if so, please do  tell!

Comment: Now that I have looked at the code, the code that provides parameters to `transform` property is there in `script.js` file. There is no straight forward way to find out what actions are bound to elements. You need to find it by trial and error way

Comment: Opening up the script debugger and searching for `cog` pretty quickly reveals the code involved in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site uses a JavaScript plugin called "TweenMax" from http://www.greensock.com, which is part of their "GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP)" product.

The usage is simple. For example:

```
TweenMax.to("#technicaldetails .cog2",1,{rotation:"-=20"});
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this website would be useful: http://croberts.me/2013/02/16/howto-rotating-gears-when-user-scrolls/

theres js, html and a codepen example

Answer (score 0):

What I do when I want to find a behaivior or a style in a site is look for the ID or class name in all the javascripts and CSSs. In this case, you can find that the `.cog` class is being used in the `scripts.js` file, in which they use the [TweenMax](http://greensock.com/tweenmax) plugin to update the cog's rotation. Check that plugin too.